# Задано двумерный вектор целых чисел Определить сумму тех элементов вектора, сумма индексов которых кратна трем

Tags: c++, матрицы, vector

Условия задачи в заголовке,я умею находить индекс элемента,но не понимаю как мне по индексу искать элемент и если сумма кратна 3 то добавлять ее в сумму,вот мой код,кто может прошу помочь дополнить

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
int sum;
int n, m;    
 cout << "Введите колличество строк" << endl;
  cin >> n;
 cout << "Введите колличество элементов в строке" << endl;
  cin >> m; 
  int index;

        vector < vector <int> > a(n, vector <int>(m)); 

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)    
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
            {
                cin >> a[i][j]; 
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
                cout << a[i][j] << ' '; 
            cout << endl;
        }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum = 0;                                   // <------------------

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
    {
        if ((i+j)%3==0) sum += a[i][j];   // <------------------
        cout << a[i][j] << ' '; 
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Добавьте указанные строки, а потом выведите sum... `(i+j)%3==0` - и есть проверка кратности суммы индексов трем.

Comment: Спасибо,помогло

Comment: Ну, принимайте ответ...